# Getting an sql connection string error when scaffolding in EF core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sqlconnection, scaffolding

For background info, I'm running .NET core on Arch Linux VScode and I also have SQL Server running on Arch Linux. When I connect to the server via `sqlcmd` or through the VScode SQL extension, everything works fine.

Only when scaffolding am I getting errors, so my connection string is probably wrong, and I've searched and basically tried everything within my grasp. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

When I run the command

```
[wasiim@wasiim-PC WebApiServerApp]$ dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=wasiim-PC;Database=ConkerDb;User Id=sa;Password=********" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -c ConkerDbContext -v
```

I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
>
> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000005, 6): No such device or address
>
> at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName)
>   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.Connect(String serverName, Int32 port, TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle..ctor(String serverName, Int32 port, Int64 timerExpire, Object callbackObject, Boolean parallel)

I've also tried doing

```
[wasiim@wasiim-PC WebApiServerApp]$ dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=(wasiim-PC)\MSSQLSERVER;Database=ConkerDb;User Id=sa;Password=********" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -c ConkerDbContext -v
```

and I get the error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

mssql error log

the errorlog display nothing about any of the connection attempts I've made so I'm assuming it didn't make a connection, and yes the service is running. I pinged wasiim-PC, pinged localhost, pinged 127.0.0.1 they're all working just fine.

```
[wasiim@wasiim-PC log]$ sudo cat errorlog
2019-07-04 14:53:24.34 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU15) (KB4498951) - 14.0.3162.1 (X64) 
        May 15 2019 19:14:30 
        Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
        Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Arch Linux)
2019-07-04 14:53:24.35 Server      UTC adjustment: -5:00
2019-07-04 14:53:24.35 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2019-07-04 14:53:24.36 Server      All rights reserved.
2019-07-04 14:53:24.36 Server      Server process ID is 32.
2019-07-04 14:53:24.36 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file '/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog'.
2019-07-04 14:53:24.37 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
         -d /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf
         -l /var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf
         -e /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog
2019-07-04 14:53:24.38 Server      SQL Server detected 1 sockets with 4 cores per socket and 8 logical processors per socket, 8 total logical processors; using 8 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2019-07-04 14:53:24.39 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2019-07-04 14:53:24.39 Server      Detected 12632 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2019-07-04 14:53:24.40 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
2019-07-04 14:53:24.41 Server      Large Page Allocated: 32MB 
2019-07-04 14:53:24.92 Server      Buffer pool extension is already disabled. No action is necessary. 
2019-07-04 14:53:25.16 Server      InitializeExternalUserGroupSid failed. Implied authentication will be disabled.
2019-07-04 14:53:25.16 Server      Implied authentication manager initialization failed. Implied authentication will be disabled.
2019-07-04 14:53:25.18 Server      Successfully initialized the TLS configuration. Allowed TLS protocol versions are ['1.0 1.1 1.2']. Allowed TLS ciphers are ['ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:!DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA'].
2019-07-04 14:53:25.21 Server      The maximum number of dedicated administrator connections for this instance is '1'
2019-07-04 14:53:25.22 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x00000000000000ff:0 Active CPU mask: 0x00000000000000ff:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2019-07-04 14:53:25.22 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2019-07-04 14:53:25.23 Server      In-Memory OLTP initialized on standard machine.
2019-07-04 14:53:25.34 Server      Database Instant File Initialization: enabled. For security and performance considerations see the topic 'Database Instant File Initialization' in SQL Server Books Online. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2019-07-04 14:53:25.35 Server      Query Store settings initialized with enabled = 1, 
2019-07-04 14:53:25.35 spid6s      Starting up database 'master'.
2019-07-04 14:53:25.35 Server      Software Usage Metrics is disabled.
2019-07-04 14:53:25.57 spid6s      Resource governor reconfiguration succeeded.
2019-07-04 14:53:25.57 spid6s      SQL Server Audit is starting the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2019-07-04 14:53:25.58 spid6s      SQL Server Audit has started the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2019-07-04 14:53:25.67 spid6s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
2019-07-04 14:53:25.69 spid6s      Server name is 'wasiim-PC'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2019-07-04 14:53:25.72 spid24s     Always On: The availability replica manager is starting. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2019-07-04 14:53:25.72 spid22s     Starting up database 'msdb'.
2019-07-04 14:53:25.72 spid23s     Starting up database 'ConkerDb'.
2019-07-04 14:53:25.72 spid9s      Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
2019-07-04 14:53:25.73 spid24s     Always On: The availability replica manager is waiting for the instance of SQL Server to allow client connections. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2019-07-04 14:53:25.74 spid9s      The resource database build version is 14.00.3162. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2019-07-04 14:53:25.78 spid9s      Starting up database 'model'.
2019-07-04 14:53:26.02 spid23s     Parallel redo is started for database 'ConkerDb' with worker pool size [4].
2019-07-04 14:53:26.02 spid19s     A self-generated certificate was successfully loaded for encryption.
2019-07-04 14:53:26.03 spid19s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 1433].
2019-07-04 14:53:26.04 spid19s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 1433].
2019-07-04 14:53:26.04 Server      Server is listening on [ ::1 <ipv6> 1434].
2019-07-04 14:53:26.04 Server      Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 1434].
2019-07-04 14:53:26.04 Server      Dedicated admin connection support was established for listening locally on port 1434.
2019-07-04 14:53:26.05 spid19s     SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2019-07-04 14:53:26.08 spid9s      Polybase feature disabled.
2019-07-04 14:53:26.09 spid9s      Clearing tempdb database.
2019-07-04 14:53:26.13 spid6s      Parallel redo is shutdown for database 'ConkerDb' with worker pool size [4].
2019-07-04 14:53:26.15 Server      Failed to verify the Authenticode signature of 'C:\binn\secforwarder.dll'. Signature verification of SQL Server DLLs will be skipped. Genuine copies of SQL Server are signed. Failure to verify the Authenticode signature might indicate that this is not an authentic release of SQL Server. Install a genuine copy of SQL Server or contact customer support.
2019-07-04 14:53:26.38 spid9s      Starting up database 'tempdb'.
2019-07-04 14:53:26.63 spid9s      The tempdb database has 1 data file(s).
2019-07-04 14:53:26.64 spid24s     The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2019-07-04 14:53:26.65 spid24s     The Database Mirroring endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2019-07-04 14:53:26.67 spid24s     Service Broker manager has started.
2019-07-04 14:53:26.70 spid6s      Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2019-07-04 14:58:44.68 spid51      Using 'dbghelp.dll' version '4.0.5'
2019-07-04 15:00:33.43 spid51      Attempting to load library 'xplog70.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2019-07-04 15:00:33.54 spid51      Using 'xplog70.dll' version '2017.140.3162' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_msver'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
```

Update: full error

> Using project '/home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/ProjectConker/WebApiServerApp/WebApiServerApp.csproj'.
>   Using startup project '/home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/ProjectConker/WebApiServerApp/WebApiServerApp.csproj'.
>   Writing '/home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/ProjectConker/WebApiServerApp/obj/WebApiServerApp.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
>   dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=/tmp/tmpDCtI3l.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo /home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/ProjectConker/WebApiServerApp/WebApiServerApp.csproj
>   Writing '/home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/ProjectConker/WebApiServerApp/obj/WebApiServerApp.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
>   dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=/tmp/tmpPGLuFn.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo /home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/ProjectConker/WebApiServerApp/WebApiServerApp.csproj
>   dotnet build /home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/ProjectConker/WebApiServerApp/WebApiServerApp.csproj /p:GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles=True /verbosity:quiet /nologo
>
> Build succeeded.
>       0 Warning(s)
>       0 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:03.18
>   dotnet exec --depsfile /home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/ProjectConker/WebApiServerApp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/WebApiServerApp.deps.json --additionalprobingpath /home/wasiim/.nuget/packages --runtimeconfig /home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/ProjectConker/WebApiServerApp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/WebApiServerApp.runtimeconfig.json /home/wasiim/.nuget/packages/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools.dotnet/2.0.3/tools/netcoreapp2.0/ef.dll dbcontext scaffold "Server=(wasiim-PC)\MSSQLSERVER;Database=ConkerDb;User Id=sa;Password=come1517" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -c ConkerDbContext --assembly /home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/ProjectConker/WebApiServerApp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/WebApiServerApp.dll --startup-assembly /home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/ProjectConker/WebApiServerApp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/WebApiServerApp.dll --project-dir /home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/ProjectConker/WebApiServerApp/ --verbose --root-namespace WebApiServerApp
>   Using assembly 'WebApiServerApp'.
>   Using startup assembly 'WebApiServerApp'.
>   Using application base '/home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/ProjectConker/WebApiServerApp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2'.
>   Using working directory '/home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/ProjectConker/WebApiServerApp'.
>   Using root namespace 'WebApiServerApp'.
>   Using project directory '/home/wasiim/Documents/CodingProjects/ProjectConker/WebApiServerApp/'.
>   Finding design-time services for provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'...
>   Using design-time services from provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'.
>   Finding design-time services referenced by assembly 'WebApiServerApp'.
>   No referenced design-time services were found.
>   Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly 'WebApiServerApp'...
>   No design-time services were found.

as you can see, before I get the exceptions it says No design-time services were found, it seems related, I searched around the web tirelessly but couldn't fix this. Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the command you use with sqlcmd?   Are you using a user name and password?  The c# connection string should be the same parameters that work with sqlcmd.

Comment: @jdweng sqlcmd -S wasiim-PC -U sa, and then fill in password

Comment: When you open SQL Server Management studio what is the Server/Instance.  SQLCMD will locate the instance of the server on the machine while the c# connection string need the server name and instance just like the login windows of SSMS.

Comment: @jdweng SSMS is not available on Linux so I'm doing everything through the VScode SQL extension. But when I query for @@servername and @@servicename I get wasiim-PC and MSSQLSERVER respectively. But as you can see in the post, that also resulted in an error, so I'm very lost.

Comment: Are you on same machine of different machine?  On you on Windows and trying to access the server on Linux? I think you should use PING wasiim-PC (on windows run from cmd.exe) and see if you have a route to the server.  I often see issues where the subnets (using the Masks) were not configured correctly and the Linux subnet was not accessible from the Windows Subnet.

Comment: @jdweng It's the same machine, on linux trying to access local database on linux.

Comment: Check log files.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-troubleshooting-guide?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @jdweng posted the error log

Comment: The log file shows the server listening on Windows (wasiim-PC) IPAny port 1433 and on Linux on loopback (127.0.0.1) port 1434.  Port 1433 is the default window port number.  the are 3 databases on server so you must specify default (msdb,ConkerDb, and mssqlsystemresource).  I think two computers on you network either have same IP address or same PC name.  Shutdown PC.  Then go to another PC and PING the IP address and then Ping Computer name and see if you get any response.  It looks like the DNS is giving error.  We have this occasionally at work where DNS has two computers with same IP.

Comment: @jdweng but I'm running everything locally on this laptop though dual booted into arch linux. I don't understand why connection would be perfectly fine using sqlcmd and VScode SQL extension but it fails when I try to scaffold.

Comment: Linux is a different subnet from the windows interface.  Linux is using the looback address 127.0.0.1 while windows is going to the DNS server to get IP address.  The IP is getting duplicated due to DCHP assignments.  If you did from cmd.exe >IPCONFIG/renew the IP may get updated and problem who get resolved.  Somebody may of hard assigned the IP address to a range that DCHP was also assigning IP.  Often there are issues when both manual assignments of IP and DCHP also is assigning IP addresses on same network.

Comment: @jdweng they're both using the same IP 192.168.1.16 and the same MAC address.

Comment: Look at the log file.

Comment: @jdweng I've looked at the log file, and from my eyes, there doesn't to be anything apparently wrong. Don't understand why Dbcontext scaffold in particular is failing to connect to the database when SQLCMD and the SQL Extension worked perfectly fine.

Comment: From linux the connection is using loopback 127.0.0.01 on port 1434.  On windows database is listening on IP.Any using port 1433.  the error meessage is from DNS server which is window.  If you are getting a DNS error is due to DCHP which is used to lookup Computer Name and return an IP.  I suspect the error is due to duplicate IP addresses being assigned.  When you attempt to make the connection in Windows you are attempting to connect to a different machine that doesn't have SQL:Server installed.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not running windows though, my database and my .NET core application are all on one machine and one OS which is linux. I have SQL server running on linux.

Comment: @jdweng updated my post, before I get the exception it says No design time services found, so I'm wondering if this is related. I looked around but can't get rid of it. If you have any ideas, can you please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: It is possible the service is set to manual start instead of automatic.  My first step is usually to run SQL Server Management Studio and see if you can open database from SSMS.

Comment: @jdweng there's no SSMS for linux, to interact with the database you'd have to use the SQL Server Extension for VScode, which works just fine for me, so database access through that medium is no problem. This problem seems to be related to .NET core. I would place a bounty on this but I don't have that many points lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran this and it just worked this time I guess:

```sh
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=wasiim-PC;Database=ConkerDb;User Id=sa;Password=*********" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -c ConkerDbContext -v
```

Answer (score 0):

That is what I've been saying.  I do not thing the Net error message are accurate.  Net is trying to make a secure TCP connection using an IP address (name) and port number.  The connection is not completing and Net is saying the error could be due to the service.  TCP errors fail for four reasons 1) No Route to server 2) Port blocked 3) Server not listening 4) TLS/SSL failing for a secure connection.

From the Log file (LDF) we can tell the SQL Server never got the connection because there is no record of a login.  I think it time to use a sniffer like wireshark of fiddler to see exactly where the connection is failing.

I do not know how to configure linux and suspect the setup is wrong.  I'm not sure if using the same IP address for both linux and windows will work.  Sending message are fine.  But when an IP is received without having a different IP address for linux and Windows the Ethernet interface does not know whether to send and receive message up 
 the Windows interface or Linux interface.  It looks like the port number in this case will be used.  Port 1433 for linux and port 1434 for windows.  Using a sniffer would confirm.  So I would first get the Net side working by using SSMS and get SSMS working which should solve the Net issue.

Answer (score 0):

At first my connection string was the following:-

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DB_NAME;Trusted_Connection=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models
```

Take case for the two `\\` int the connection string and that's was the problem.

Then I made it like so and it worked for me.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=DB_NAME;Trusted_Connection=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models
```